# Arduino powered by rpi3

Tags: arduino, usb-power

I hooked my Arduino UNO to one of the USB port of my rpi3.
The Arduino itself power a small light sensor, later on i plan on adding LCD display, LEDs, etc
Can the pi handle it without any fuss ?

My project is time sensitive.
I tried separating the power source, and feed the Arduino by another supply.
And then use the pi Tx/Rx, to communicate with the Arduino by serial.
It just added more complexity to a rather simple setup.

My setup:
rPi3 powered by a 2A supply
Sensor hooked to Arduino pins(+5v, GND, A0 pin), consumes 4mA
Arduino hooked to rPi by USB

Comment: How can we tell?  You need to calculate how much current the Arduino will need when fully loaded and check that the Pi has enough spare capacity.

Comment: My sensor sips 4mA from the Arduino.

Comment: There's no way to answer this with the information that you've given. We need to know a lot more details about the set-up.

Comment: Edited, added the setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I routinely run Arduino from USB ports on the Pi, although you can also use the 5V pin on the header to supply power.

The Pi can supply 600mA (at least) from USB and up to 1A from the 5V pin (given an adequate power supply) so should have no problem running any Arduino. If the project will run from the Arduino power the Pi will be OK.

See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

Comment: So I can draw up to 600 mA from RPi USB ?